# Import data in R from access 365

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, office365

I got an update at work from office 2010 to office 365. 
I was using this code to import files from access 2010 to R:

```
library(RODBC)    #loads the RODBC package

dta <- odbcConnectAccess2007("F:/database.accdb")
```

With access 365 is not working anymore. I get this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: I don't want to change your code, but please don't put `rm(list = ls())` in your questions. If someone runs your code without noticing that line, they've deleted everything from their working environment, which they probably don't want to do. Also, without any data, we can't reproduce what you're doing (although tbh I don't know how to make an Access question reproducible...)

Comment: I deleted it, sorry.

Comment: Please see if any MS Access lines output from `odbcDataSources()`.

Comment: I get named character(0)